# Javascript: Convert map to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object

I am new to programming in general and am looking to convert a Javascript map into array of objects. For example, convert the input constant into the output constant:

```
const input = new Map([
   [1, 'one'],
   [2, 'two'],
   [3, 'three'],
]);

const output = [
    { number: 1, letter: 'one' },
    { number: 2, letter: 'two' },
    { number: 3, letter: 'three' }
];
```

This might be a simple code but I cannot find any reference. Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
const output = Array.from(input).map(([number, letter]) => ({number, letter}));
```

The basic idea is that you convert the map `input` to an array, and then map each entry.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to convert to anything. There is a forEach method for Map. You can do the following using [Map.protoType.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach),

```js
const input = new Map([
   [1, 'one'],
   [2, 'two'],
   [3, 'three'],
]);

let output = [];

input.forEach((letter, number) => {
  output.push({number, letter});
})

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Upvoted because compared to the other solution this is more space efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Use `...` operator and `map` method.

```js
const input = new Map([
   [1, 'one'],
   [2, 'two'],
   [3, 'three'],
]);

const output = [...input].map(([number, letter]) => ({number, letter}))

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by iterating over the Map using For-of iteration and pushing the object into a new array. Refer to [for-of operation for Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```
var arr = [];
for(var [key, val] of input) {
  arr.push({ integer: key, letter: val})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to other answers, this one does not create an unnecessary intermediate array:

```js
const input = new Map([
  [1, 'one'],
  [2, 'two'],
  [3, 'three'],
]);
const output = Array.from(input, ([number, letter]) => ({number, letter}));
console.log(output);
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#description):

> `Array.from()` has an optional parameter `mapFn`, which allows you to execute a function on each element of the array being created, similar to `map()`. More clearly, `Array.from(obj, mapFn, thisArg)` has the same result as `Array.from(obj).map(mapFn, thisArg)`, except that it does not create an intermediate array, and `mapFn` only receives two arguments (`element`, `index`) without the whole array, because the array is still under construction.